# There's any way to add a border to a spinner?

Tags: android-studio

I have an app with many activities with spinners inside but some people doesn't realize that is a clickable area with more text, so, I was thinking in to add some border to the spinner to make it look more like a PC app DropDownBox because currently is only the text and a little arrow on the right side.